# Arrastrar y seleccionar elementos (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando crear algo parecido al explorador de archivos de Windows y no tengo idea de por donde empezar a implementar esto, quisiera que al arrastrar el mouse con el click sostenido vaya sombreando y seleccionando todo por donde pase el cuadro de selección.

Me gustaría saber cuales serian las bases para hacer esto o si existe algo Framework o librería para esto.

Este es mi proyecto:
[image: Mi propio explorador de archivos]

***Me gustaria lograr algo como esto:***
[image: Explorador de Windows]

Comment: cada elemento html tiene la prop ondrop o drop creo, y ahi optiones el datatransfer del event y luego esta en files croe o imprime en consola que te da.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera para seleccionar las carpetas sería usar los eventos mousedown, mousemove y mouseup para guardar la posición del mouse en cada momento en un state, por ejemplo:

```
const [cursorPos, setCursorPos] = useState({
    currentX: null,
    currentY: null,
    initialX: null,
    initialY: null,
    xOffset : 0,
    yOffset: 0,
    event:null ,
    moving: false,
    mousedown: false,   
    drawing: false
})

const handleMouseDown = (e, id) => {            
    ...
        setCursorPos({
            ...

            initialX: e.clientX .. // Aqui se guarda la posición inicial
                             ,
            initialY:    e.clientY  // Aqui se guarda la posición inicial
                            
            ...
        })
}


const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    ...     
        setCursorPos({
            ...cursorPos,
            moving: true,
            currentX: e.clientX ... // aqui se guarda la posición actual
                
            currentY: e.clientY ... // aqui se guarda la posición actual
            , 
    
        })
}
```

Al pasar el mouse por encima de  la carpeta se cambia el estado a activo y al salir a inactivo usado useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {

    ...

        setBoxes(Boxes.map(b =>
            !b.active
                ?   stillWithinSelectionArea(cursorPos ,b.id, getBoxesCoords(screenRef)) // aquí se verifica si el mouse esta sobre la carpeta 
                        ? {...b, active: true}
                        : b
                :   stillWithinSelectionArea(cursorPos ,b.id, getBoxesCoords(screenRef))
                    ? b
                    :  {...b, active: false}
        

        ))

}, [cursorPos])
```

Y para dibujar el selector se pueden obtener las coordenadas a partir de la posición actual e inicial del mouse.

Aquí dejo el link de codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-torvalds-jfngo?file=/src/App.js:1428-1819

Comment: ¡Muchísimas Gracias! Una pregunta más, ¿de cual propiedad puedo sacar los Id de los elementos seleccionados?

Comment: De nada, normalmente se obtienen del evento del mouse, event.target.id, pero en mi ejemplo los obtuve del ref del screen, (screenRef.current.childNodes.[i].id), depende de como lo quieras implementar